# Is the Rails update_attributes method the best choice for doing an update of a model in the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, updatemodel, update-attributes

```
def update
  @album = Album.find(params[:id])
  if @album.update_attributes(params[:album])
    redirect_to(:action=>'list')
  else
    render(:action=>'edit')
  end    
end
```

A Rails 1.1.6 tutorial that I'm covering recommends using the `update_attributes` method for updating a model, as in the example code from my controller listed above. Looking at the Rails documentation I'm wondering why the `update` method would not have been preferred, especially since it is named so logically.

Comment: This article about *[5 Ways To Set Attributes In ActiveRecord](http://www.davidverhasselt.com/2011/06/28/5-ways-to-set-attributes-in-activerecord/)* might of interest.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Update takes an object `id` parameter and a set of attributes that otherwise work like `update_attributes`.

So this (from [AWDWR 3rd edition](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails-third-edition))

```
Order.update(12, :name => "Barney", :email => "barney@bedrock.com")
```

is equivalent to

```
Order.find(12).update_attributes(:name => "Barney", :email => "barney@bedrock.com")
```

So if all you want to do is update a row of known id with a set of attributes then I'd say there's no reason not to use `update` - it looks like that's the reason they wrote it!

(Is there any way you can get your tutorial to upgrade from 1.1.6? It's pretty old and wasn't a particularly earth-shattering release when it was current. 1.2.6 was better - the last of the 1.xs, if I remember correctly).

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet - that makes sense. No, it's not upgradeable, unfortunately. It's a lynda.com video series - it's really quite a good introduction to Rails for me although I will probably need to read a more up-to-date text after I finish it. First I need to understand the Big Picture, which I had been having a hard time with after reading the O'Reilly book "Head First Rails" a few months back.

Answer (score 0):

Using update_attributes method just suppose that you already have an object, and you would just pass the  set of attributes. And the work is done !