# Update attributes by id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to update attributes of a model:

```
  def update
    MyModel.update_attributes params[:id], params[:mymodel]
    #.....
  end
```

But it says `` undefined method `update_attributes' for #<Class:0x0000000396ecb0> ``. I wonder, isn't this the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/840323/1708058

Comment: model do not have attributes, instance has attributes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`update_attributes` is an instance method of `ActiveRecord::Relation`, you have to use the class method [`update`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update):

```
MyModel.update(params[:id], params[:mymodel])
```

To use `update_attributes` you could do:

```
@my_model = MyModel.find(params[:id])
@my_model.update_attributes(params[:mymodel])
```